# Pdf+Tex - figures side by side with minipage

Tags: minipage, sidebyside

This is a working example of putting two pdf-figures side by side with minipage:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44 \textwidth}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{1.pdf} 
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{2.pdf}
\end{minipage}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

However, using instead pdf+tex pictures I can't use the option "scale" anymore, since only the pdf-file becomes smaller, but not the text in the tex-file.
Instead I am using the command resizebox, but I am not able to put two pdf+tex figures next to each other (side by side) with minipage.

In this example one pdf+tex figure is below the other one:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}

\begin{minipage}[h]{0.47 \textwidth}
  \def\svgwidth{3.8in}
  \resizebox{!}{0.3\paperheight}{\input{picture1.tex}}
     \label{fig:pic1}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[h]{0.47 \textwidth}
  \def\svgwidth{2.3in}
  \resizebox{!}{0.3\paperheight}{\input{picture2.tex}}
     \label{fig:pic2}
\end{minipage}

\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

No effect had the change of textwidth to linewidth.

Comment: your first example will put the minipages one above the other, not side by side, since you have a paragraph break between them. in the second example `minipage `does not have an `h` option. The minipages ae one above the other just as in the first example, due to the blank line making a paragraph

Comment: welcome to tex.se. searching trough site will show you, that your question is duplicate :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Your initial example shouldn't work - there must not be an empty line between two `minipage` environments when you want them to be put next to each other. But leaving that out, this works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44 \textwidth}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{1.pdf} 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[scale=0.55]{2.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To your actual question: When going from `\includegraphics` to `\input` (e.g. when having a SVG exported with Inkscape to PDF+TeX), you have three options:

1. `\scalebox{0.55}{\input{mypicture.tex}}` to *scale* the image by some factor (this is closest to what you were doing above).
2. `\resizebox{0.44\textwidth}{!}{\input{mypicture.tex}}` to *resize* the picture to some fixed width.
3. `\resizebox{!}{0.3\textheight}{\input{mypicture.tex}}` to *resize* the picture to some fixed height.

I would always suggest to use option 2, i.e. to specify the width of the inputed part, because you can easily synchronize that with the width of your `minipage` environments. Actually, `\textwidth` inside a `minipage` will always be the full size of the minipage. Example (without `\input` but the principle of `resizebox` is the same):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44\textwidth}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\textwidth}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]